# Google Places reference mysql field type

Tags: mysql, google-places-api

triying to store a place, from google places api v3. There is a field named "reference" but I don't know what type of field can I use to store it. Actually, in mysql I'm using `TinyText` but I saw `varchar(255)` on some places.

The api says:

> reference contains a token that can be used to query the Details service in future. This token may differ from the reference used in the request to the Details service. It is recommended that stored references for Places be regularly updated. Although this token uniquely identifies the Place, the converse is not true: a Place may have many valid reference tokens.

But it does not especify the type of field returned, nor the longitude. Any clue?

Comment: _“I'm using TinyText but I saw varchar(255) on some places”_ – you are aware that TINYTEXT stores up to 255 characters as well, right?

Comment: Yep, using the same weight. But I wonder if it's valid, or I'm storing it on a field with a type with not the necesary lenght, or if I can do it smaller.